# how to reference an existing resource group in azure resource templates

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Does any know how I can use the [reference function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#reference) to reference a existing resourcegroup in a azure resource templates.

I would like to know the location of a specfic resource (West europe, West us etc) because I needed as input for an another resource. The resource that I reference is not in the same resourcegroup

Comment: could you clarify that? what does that mean? you can't make any decision based on that knowledge anyway

Answer (score 1):

If we want to create the traffic manager with ARM and config  `azureEndpoints` endpoint. **We no need to add location property**. We can get that by target resource id, The following is my test code, it works correctly for me.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "variables": {
    "tmApiVersion": "2015-11-01"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('tmApiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles",
      "name": "azureendpointexample",
      "location": "global",
      "properties": {
        "profileStatus": "Enabled",
        "trafficRoutingMethod": "Performance",
        "dnsConfig": {
          "relativeName": "azureendpointexample",
          "ttl": 30
        },
        "monitorConfig": {
          "protocol": "http",
          "port": 80,
          "path": "/"
        },
        "endpoints": [
          {
            "name": "tomtest",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/azureEndpoints",
            "properties": {
              "endpointStatus": "Enabled",
              "endpointMonitorStatus": null,
              "targetResourceId": "[resourceId('resourcegroup', 'Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'websitename')]",
              "target": "azureendpointexample.azurewebsites.net",
              "weight": 1,
              "priority": 1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Check it from the Azure portal[image].

Answer (score 0):

Not all resources support returning the location (keep in mind some are geo-redundant) maybe more detail behind the question, i.e. what resources are you trying to connect, might help.

Here's an example of getting the primary storage location:

```
[reference(resourceId(parameters('storageAccountResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'), '2016-01-01').primaryLocation]
```

But for something like a VM's VHD, a managed disk would be easier...  So knowing more about the scenario might lead to a better solution...